# Python: Random item from list combining only two

Tags: python

I'm making a slot machine program in Python and for some reason, the random selector wants to combine a known two elements.

```
    itmlist = random.choice(['banana', 'cherry', 'bar', 'seven', 'banana', 'cherry' 'banana', 'cherry', 'seven'])
    print itmlist
```

It shows up as "cherrybanana" every once in a while and I am really confused.

Comment: have pity on the maintainer of your code and create the list as `['banana'] * 3 + ['cherry'] * 3 + ['seven'] * 2 + ['bar']`

Answer (score 11):

You miss a comma between 'cherry' and 'banana' near the end of the list.

Python concatenate the strings so it becomes 'cherrybanana'

itmlist = random.choice(['banana', 'cherry', 'bar', 'seven', 'banana', **'cherry' 'banana'**, 'cherry', 'seven'])

Comment: @Kimvais' suggestion would avoid this problem neatly. You could also have diagnosed it by storing the list separately (you may well need the same list in a few different places, if you're doing what I think you're doing) and printing it to verify its contents.